# Kernel and Lie-bracket of 1-forms

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$ be a 1-form on a manifold $M$ which vanishes no-where. Given that for any two vector fields $X$, $Y \in \ker{\alpha}$ there holds $[X,Y] \in \ker{\alpha}$ ($[.,.]$ is the Lie bracket) does there holds $\alpha \wedge d \alpha = 0$ with $d$ the exterior derivative?
The other direction is true but I can't see how to prove this direction or to give a counterexample.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion: choose a local frame $(E_1,\dots,E_n)$ with dual coframe $(\epsilon^1,\dots,\epsilon^n)$, such that $\alpha=\epsilon^1$. Then use the formula $d\alpha(E_i,E_j) = E_i(\alpha(E_j)) - E_j(\alpha(E_i)) - \alpha([E_i,E_j])$.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't then $ \alpha \wedge d \alpha =0$?

Comment: My suggestion was meant to be a way to prove that if $\ker \alpha$ is closed under Lie bracket, then $\alpha\wedge d\alpha=0$.

Comment: Sorry for my poor background, but what does closer under Lie Bracket means?

Comment: The term is "closed" under Lie bracket. It's what you wrote: If $X,Y$ are vector fields that take values in $\ker{\alpha}$, then their Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ also takes its values in $\ker{\alpha}$.

Comment: Is a local frame the vector field induced by a chart? I can't see why $\alpha \wedge d \alpha =0$ by what you wrote.

Comment: No, a local frame need not be induced by a chart. It's not meant to be obvious why $\alpha\wedge d\alpha=0$; I wanted to leave some work for you to do!